# Compile errors with one project only after adding a second project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, compiler-errors, google-diff-match-patch

I have a solution in VS2012 that compiles fine.  I wanted to write some unit tests for it and found [WinUnit](http://winunit.codeplex.com/).

For ease, I pulled the WinUnit test project into my solution.

I stripped out their sample file, and began to reference my copy of [Google's diff_match_patch](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) that I wanted to test.

As soon as I add the .h file to my project and compile, I get 3 errors in the diff_match_patch file.  This file compiled just fine before I added the new project.

> Error  3   error C2059: syntax error : '(' ...\diff_match_patch.h  103 1   TestSampleLib
>
> Error  4   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  ...\diff_match_patch.h  104 1   TestSampleLib
>
> Error  5   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'  ...\diff_match_patch.h  104 1   TestSampleLib

All the errors center around this code:

```
enum Operation {
   DELETE, INSERT, EQUAL
};
```

I thought it might be some reference that I'm missing, but I've added everything I can think of and its still failing the compile.

These are the only errors i'm getting, so I cant figure out the root cause.

What could make this otherwise compilable file fail?

Comment: There are probably bad #define macros in that .h file that conflict with your identifiers.

Comment: @n.m. I really did strip out that unit test file.  It has only the .h reference, and an empty `BEGIN_TEST` function  from WinUnit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems macro name pollution. You can try to #undef all the names just before the definition of the enum and see what happens.

Comment: While not exactly the answer, the pollution is what is happening.  There was a `#define DELETE` in winnt.h that was being included in my unit test project.  Excellent, thank you!